# Ninjas: Dadas unas coordenadas, sacar css transform (skew, rotate ) pintar una imagen

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, css-transform

la API me devuelve unas coordenadas random que será el contenedor de la imagen, y estas coordenadas siempre serán un rectángulo pero puede que no tenga los angulos de 90 grados por lo que tengo que deformar la imagen para adaptarlo a este contenedor.

Creo que la solución sería transofomar las coordenadas a css-transform.
¿A alguien se le ocurre algo?

Gracias.

```js
var app = {
  init: function() {
    let coords = this.getDataFromApi(); // getting coords
    this.reDrawPolygon(coords);
    this.positionateImg(coords);
  },

  getDataFromApi: () => {
    /* http request with random points*/
    return {
      "p1": {
        "x": 28,
        "y": 51
      },
      "p2": {
        "x": 393,
        "y": 21
      },
      "p3": {
        "x": 401,
        "y": 170
      },
      "p4": {
        "x": 40,
        "y": 135
      }
    };
  },
  reDrawPolygon: (coords) => {
    let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    let points = [];
    for (let i in coords) {
      points.push(coords[i].x + ' ' + coords[i].y)
    }
    if (!svg.querySelector('polygon').getAttribute('points')) {
      svg.querySelector('polygon').setAttribute('points', points.join())
    } else {
      svg.querySelector('polygon').setAttribute('points', svg.querySelector('animate').getAttribute('to'))
    }
    svg.querySelector('animate').setAttribute('to', points.join())
    let anim = document.getElementById('animation-to-click');
    anim['beginElement']()
  },
  positionateImg: (coords) => {
    let img = document.querySelector('img');
    img.style.top = coords.p1.y + 'px';
    img.style.left = coords.p1.x + 'px';
    img.style.width = (coords.p2.x - coords.p1.x) + 'px';
    img.style.height = (coords.p4.y - coords.p1.y) + 'px';
  }

}

app.init();
```

```css
div {
  position: relative
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 600ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYOz3O64CoAaQUStkjHStEJZVADvfOlbVzjPok68XTeT-ytdGH" />
  <svg>
  <polygon style="stroke:#b5bf03;fill:transparent;stroke-width:3" points="0,0,0,0"> 
    <animate id="animation-to-click" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="100ms" />
  </polygon>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Una pregunta interesante. Habia pensado en `transform: matrix()` pero el resultado siempre es un paralelogramo y no vale para tu ejemplo. Supongo que con `matrix3d()` será posible pero no tengo ni idea de los cálculos que habría que hacer para convertir las coordenadas. Igual esto te sirve para pillar la idea: https://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/

Comment: Estoy leyendo y leyendo y si parece que necesito matrix3d pero no consigo hacerme con la fórmula... ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿A ver esto?: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033

Answer (score 0):

Esta no es exactamente una respuesta sino una demostración que es probablemente imposible hacer lo que tu quieres con transformaciones. No tengo un "slider" para para sesgar la imagen pero no creo que sería de gran ayuda. Si crees que `transform: matrix3d()`es la solución puedes probar crear algo parecido con 16 "sliders" y probar a ver si consigues deformar la imagen a tu gusto.

Por favor abra la siguiente demo a "Página completa".

```js
var s = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(s);

var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

var theParent = document.getElementById("parent");

var to = document.getElementById("to");
var radiosX = document.querySelectorAll("input[name = 'X']");
var radiosY = document.querySelectorAll("input[name = 'Y']");

var cssObject = {
  perspective: 100,
  rotateX: 0,
  rotateY: 0,
  rotateZ: 0,
  translateZ: 0,
  transformOriginX: "center",
  transformOriginY: "center"
};

for (var i = 0; i < theParent.children.length; i++) {
  var childElement = theParent.children[i];
  var theId = theParent.children[i].id;
  var theIndex = i;
  cssObject[theId] = document.querySelector("#" + theId + " input").value;
  childElement.addEventListener('input', onInput, false);
}

function onInput(e) {
  var itemId = e.target.id;
  var thisValue = document.getElementById(itemId).value;
  document.querySelector("label[for = " + itemId + " ]" + " span").innerHTML = thisValue;
  cssObject[itemId.replace("Input", "")] = thisValue;
  manipulateCSS(cssObject);
}

for (var i = 0; i < radiosX.length; i++) {
  radiosX[i].addEventListener("change",
    onChecked, false);

}
for (var i = 0; i < radiosY.length; i++) {
  radiosY[i].addEventListener("change",
    onChecked, false);
}

function onChecked(e) {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    var itemId = e.target.id;
    var thisName = e.target.name;
    var thisValue = document.getElementById(itemId).value;
    cssObject["transformOrigin" + thisName] = thisValue;
    manipulateCSS(cssObject);
  }
}

function manipulateCSS(cssObject) {
  var stylesStr1 = "perspective(" + cssObject.perspective + "px) rotateY(" + cssObject.rotateY + "deg)  rotateX(" + cssObject.rotateX + "deg) rotateZ(" + cssObject.rotateZ + "deg) translateZ(" + cssObject.translateZ + "px);";
  var stylesStr2 = cssObject.transformOriginX + " " + cssObject.transformOriginY;
  to.innerHTML = stylesStr2;
  s.textContent = "#div1{";
  s.textContent += "-webkit-transform:" + stylesStr1;
  s.textContent += "transform:" + stylesStr1;
  s.textContent += "-webkit-transform-origin:" + stylesStr2 + ";";
  s.textContent += "transform-origin:" + stylesStr2 + ";";
  s.textContent += "}";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
}
#contenido {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
#demo {
  padding: 70px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
h4 {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  font-size: 140;
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 150%;
}
p label {
  width: 38%;
  display: inline-block;
}
p input {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
}
p input[type = "radio"] {
  width: 50%;
}
.div {
  background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYOz3O64CoAaQUStkjHStEJZVADvfOlbVzjPok68XTeT-ytdGH");
  width:313px;
  height:161px;
  
}
.row {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
._2 {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}



svg{position:absolute;margin:auto; left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0;width:296;height:118.24; z-index:2 }
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
<svg viewBox = "28 21 373 149" style="border:1px solid">
<polygon style="stroke:#b5bf03;fill:transparent;stroke-width:3" points="28 51 393 21 401 170 40 135"> 
</polygon>  
  </svg>
<div id="demo">
 <div class="div" id="div1"></div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="row" id="parent">
<p id="perspective"><label for="perspectiveInput">perspective: <span>100</span>px</label>
<input type="range" value="100" min="0" max="400" id="perspectiveInput" autocomplete="off"></p>

<p id="rotateX"><label for="rotateXInput">rotateX: <span>0</span>deg</label>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-180" max="180" id="rotateXInput" autocomplete="off"></p>

<p id="rotateY"><label for="rotateYInput">rotateY: <span>0</span>deg</label>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-180" max="180" id="rotateYInput" autocomplete="off"></p>

<p id="rotateZ"><label for="rotateZInput">rotateZ: <span>0</span>deg</label>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-360" max="360" id="rotateZInput" autocomplete="off"></p>

<p id="translateZ"><label for="translateZInput">translateZ: <span>0</span>px</label>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-200" max="200" id="translateZInput" autocomplete="off"></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
<h4>transform-origin: <span id="to">center center</span></h4>
<div class="_2" id="radiosX">
<p>
<label for="r1">left: </label><input type="radio" name="X" id="r1" value="left" />
<label for="r2">center: </label><input type="radio" name="X" id="r2" value="center"  checked />
<label for="r3">right: </label><input type="radio" name="X" id="r3" value="right" />
</p>
</div><div class="_2" id="radiosY">
<p>
<label for="r4">top: </label><input type="radio" name="Y" id="r4" value="top"/>
<label for="r5">center: </label><input type="radio" name="Y" id="r5" value="center"  checked />
<label for="r6">bottom: </label><input type="radio" name="Y" id="r6" value="bottom" />
</p>
</div>
</div>
```